# How to change the route in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess

I have a web route problem in which one is badly located and I want to change it or redirect the one I want with the **.htaccess** file of my web page. Try creating a **RewriteRule** but it did not work. Could you help me?

Erroneous route: `mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/foto.jpg` Route that I want you to address or change: `mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/foto`

Here is my RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/?$ $1/photos/thumbnail$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Copied without attribution from [Cómo cambiar la ruta en HTACCESS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/275733)

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule in top of your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^swf\/c_images\/navigator-thumbnail\/(.*)\.jpg$ /photos/thumbnail/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Rule rewrite your link

```
mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/foto.jpg <> mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/foto
```

and all jpg foto in /swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/ to /photos/thumbnail/

```
mysite.com/swf/c_images/navigator-thumbnail/any-foto.jpg <> mysite.com/photos/thumbnail/any-foto
```